# Jenkins Remote Access API: Retrieve up-to-date parameter choices

Tags: jenkins, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-groovy

I'm currently building my choices depending on available agents and its labels in a pipeline:

```
def loadConfigurations() {
    def configurations = [];

    def jenkins = Jenkins.instance;
    def onlineComputers = jenkins.computers.findAll { it.online };
    def availableLabels = onlineComputers.collect {
            it.assignedLabels.collect { LabelAtom.escape(it.expression) } }
        .flatten().unique(false);

    def lineage16Configurations = ['samsung:klte:lineage:16.0'];

    if (availableLabels.containsAll(['lineage', '16.0'])) {
        configurations.addAll(lineage16Configurations);
    }

    return configurations;
}

def configurations = loadConfigurations();

pipeline {
    agent { label 'master' }
    parameters {
        choice name: 'CONFIG', choices: configurations, description: 'Configuration containing vendor, device, OS and its version. Each separated by a colon.'
    }
//...
```

Now, lets say all agents are offline, when requesting the remote access API I don't get up-to-date choices cause they're only updated when starting a build. Is there any existing way to retrieve them somehow through remote access API or do I need to write my own plugin which adds a new endpoint for the remote access API?

I've already tried the Active Choices Parameter and the Extended Choice Parameter without success. Both don't display any choices in the API.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was playing around with the Extensible Choice Parameter and created a [Pull Request](https://github.com/jenkinsci/extensible-choice-parameter-plugin/pull/43) which exposes the choiceList to the Remote Access API. The API was then returning changed choices without building the job.